# findOne with $push create duplicate objects

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update an object in the collection that has an array of objects. The problem is that my code create duplicate objects in the array.

```
exports.add_collection = (req, res) => {
  let coll = {collName: req.body.collName, collApps: []}

  console.log(coll)
  User.updateOne({_id: req.userId}, { $push: {collections: coll} },
                                    //seems like $push pushes twice?!
    (err) => {
      if(err){
        console.log("Error: ", err)
      }
    })
  .then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "collection added",
      collection: coll
    })
  })
}
```

in MongoDB, I have something like this

```
//some elements of the documents
"collections": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5c8ed..."
            },
            "collName": "Social Media",
            "collApps": []
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5c8ed..."
            },
            "collName": "Social Media",
            "collApps": []
        },
//other elements of the documents
```

Comment: It looks like you have an answer for how to work around this issue, but we still don't know where the issue is coming from in the first place. If I had to guess, I would bet that there are actually multiple requests hitting that end point, and that your problem is actually in figuring out why your requests are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with `$addToSet` instead of `$push`.

**$addToSet** - Add just unique items, but order of items is not guarantied.

**$push** - You can add same items several times.